# Can I define a Map<String, List<? extends BaseView>> so that I can get() a list from the map without unchecked casting?

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting

I have the following Java code to get a number of collections related to an object in several locations:

```
Map<String, List<? extends BaseView>> additionalCollections = deployEnvironmentService.getInputPageInfo(getProjectOid());
List<MachineView> machineViews = (List<MachineView>) additionalCollections.get("machineViewCollection");
List<LevelView> levelViews = (List<LevelView>) additionalCollections.get("levelViewCollection");
List<ToolView> toolViews = (List<ToolView>) additionalCollections.get("toolViewCollection");
List<BuildEnvironmentView> buildEnvironmentViews = (List<BuildEnvironmentView>) additionalCollections
                .get("buildEnvironmentViewCollection");
```

The name and number of collections varies based on the service I use, but the collections always inherit from BaseView. The collections are retrieved in a method similar to this:

```
public Map<String,List<? extends BaseView>> getInputPageInfo(Integer projectOid) {
    Map<String,List<? extends BaseView>> allInfoMap = new HashMap<String,List<? extends BaseView>>();
    PersistenceBroker broker = PersistenceBrokerFactory.createPersistenceBroker();
    try {
        allInfoMap.put("levelViewCollection", getLevelViewCollection(broker, projectOid));
        allInfoMap.put("machineViewCollection", getMachineViewCollection(broker));
        allInfoMap.put("toolViewCollection", getToolViewCollection(broker, projectOid));

        allInfoMap.put("buildEnvironmentViewCollection", getBuildEnvironments(broker, projectOid));

    } finally {
        broker.close();
    }
    return allInfoMap;
}
```

The problem I have is that I always get warnings on the Map.get() methods in the first snippet, saying `Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#1-of ? extends BaseView> to Collection<LevelView>`. Is there a way to solve this warning? I've tried defining a type `<T extends BaseView>`, but then I can't find a way to use that type T in the function call itself.

Comment: Why would you want to keep them in a `Map` in the first place? Just create a class with the individual `List`s as properties, with correctly typed getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your map in a "lookup" object, and type your keys:

```
public final class PageInfoKey<T extends BaseView> {
    public static final PageInfoKey<MachineView> MACHINE_VIEWS
            = new PageInfoKey<>("machineViews", MachineView.class);
    /*... more static final keys defined here ...*/

    /* Adding the 'name' and 'type' fields,
     * and equals() and hashCode() as below,
     * allow us to have multiple instances of keys
     * defined elsewhere if desired, which should still
     * work with the lookup.
     *
     * If all keys are defined statically inside this class
     * (i.e. constructor is made private), then these fields
     * and methods are unnecessary.
     */

     private final String name;
     private final Class<T> type;

     public PageInfoKey(String name, Class<T> type) {
         this.name = name;
         this.type = type;
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
         return Objects.hash(name, type);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object other) {
         if(other==this) return true;
         if(other instanceof PageInfoKey) {
             PageInfoKey<?> o = (PageInfoKey<?>)other;
             return Objects.equals(this.name, o.name) &&
                     Objects.equals(this.type, o.type);
         }
         return false;
     }
}

public class PageInfoLookup {

    private final Map<PageInfoKey<?>, List<? extends BaseView>> data = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends BaseView> void put(PageInfoKey<T> key, List<T> value) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends BaseView> List<T> get(PageInfoKey<T> key) {
        return (List<T>) data.get(key);
    }

}
```

Now you can get your views out by passing in the statically defined key:

```
List<MachineView> machineViews = lookup.get(PageInfoKey.MACHINE_VIEWS);
```

Everything is type-safe and checked at compile time, provided you only modify/access the map via the public methods in the lookup class. There's also no need to only define your keys inside the `PageInfoKey` class - as long as there's a sensibly-defined `equals` and `hashCode` method on that class, you can define new instances anywhere you like, including in dependent libraries.

As [Aleksander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5715404/aleksandr-mukhalov) pointed out, if you know that there will only ever be at most one list of a particular type in the map, then you can just use the `Class` itself as the key.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `<Class, List<? extends BaseView>>` as the type of the map?

Comment: Depends on whether or not they want the map to contain multiple lists of the same concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.
You can only safely cast to `BaseView`, because you are sure that every list in your map either holds `BaseView` has something that extends it.
As [daniu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2837741/daniu) has suggested, you can have a class that has all the necessary lists.

If you absolutely need to use a `String` as the key, you can instantiate an unmodifiable map with typechecking done by yourself, and just supperssing the warning.